# QML Editable Tab title within TabView on double-click

Tags: qt, tabs, qml, tabbar, tabview

Is it possible to achieve a possibility of editing title of a tab within TabView after double-click it? I mean exactly something as follows.

[image]

I had a look at Tab, TabView and TabBar documentation, but I didn't find anything which could help to implement mentioned functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed anything in any other item in QML. By using `states`, one can let the TabButton behave in different states (duh), in this case an `"editing"` state, where some parts are only show during that state and others are hidden.

You should place the following in some qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

TabButton {
    id: btn

    onDoubleClicked: state = "editing"

    TextField {
        id: editor
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: btn.text
        visible: false
        onAccepted: {
            btn.text = text
            btn.state = ""
        }
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "editing"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: editor
                focus: true
                visible: true
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: btn
                explicit: true
                restoreEntryValues: false
                text: "" //so the text won't show up during editing
            }
        }
    ]
}
```